# API or scrape Google Jobs

Tags: web-scraping

I want to record the job posting information from [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sustainability%20jobs%20in%20MI&ibp=htl;jobs#fpstate=tldetail&htidocid=-ywReVqQOTSxjsEPAAAAAA%3D%3D&htivrt=jobs). Is anyone aware of an API or can you confirm it's possible to scrape with Python beautiful soup? (I'm familiar with scraping, I just can't see how to get this website)

Comment: Yes We can use JSOUP api to scrape the given Job posting info.

Comment: Today, in early 2024, you can also use Job APIs that are listed on [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/category/Jobs), [APIlist](https://apilist.fun/category/jobs), or [APIfy](https://apify.com/store/categories/jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure: I work at SerpApi.**

---

You can use [`google-search-results`](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-python) package to get data from Google Jobs listings. [Check a demo at Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MarriedGargantuanApplicationpackage).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google_jobs",
    "q": "sustainability jobs in mi",
    "google_domain": "google.com",
    "api_key":
    "API_KEY"
}

client = GoogleSearch(params)
data = client.get_dict()

print("Job results")

for job_result in data['jobs_results']:
  print(f"""Title: {job_result['title']}
Company name: {job_result['company_name']}

Description: {job_result['description']}
""")

print("Filters")

for chip in data['chips']:
  print(f"Type: {chip['type']}\n")

  print("Options")
  for option in chip['options']:
    print(option['text'])
```

Response

```
{
  "jobs_results":[
    {
      "title":"Sustainability Analyst",
      "company_name":"Amcor",
      "location":"Ann Arbor, MI",
      "via":"via LinkedIn",
      "description":"Amcor Limited Job Posting\n\nRole: Sustainability Analyst\n\nLocation: TBD, ideally in the US (Ann Arbor, MI)\n\nAbout Amcor\n\nAmcor (ASX: AMC;\n\nAmcor is proud of its recent pledge to design all of our packaging to be recyclable or reusable by 2025. The job holder will play a very important and exciting role in Amcor’s journey to deliver this important commitment.\n\nPosition Overview\n\nRead more about Amcor’s sustainability commitment:\n\nThe Sustainability function plays a key role in positioning Amcor as THE leading packaging company for the environment delivering on Amcor’s sustainability strategy, the 2025 pledge and as a supplier of choice for responsible packaging.\n\nThe Sustainability Analyst is responsible for analyzing, reporting, and coordinating selected global Sustainability activities with direction from the VP Sustainability.\n\nEssential Responsibilities And Duties\n• Track legislative activity, analyze for risk and opportunity, help to prioritize actions\n• Assist with drafting... positions, coordinate Amcor activity and governance around advocacy (mostly in industry group participation)\n• Assists with internal reporting and communications, including preparing decks for internal meetings\n• Partnership administration, tracking projects and payments, and liaising with corporate finance on dept budget\n• Manage compliance statements, including anti-slavery statements, conflict minerals etc.\n• Coordinates the International Costal Cleanup, as needed with other partners\n• Other similar duties as required to support the corporate sustainability program\n\nQualifications\n• Education: Master's Degree or equivalent in related field preferred\n• Three to five years of experience\n• Strong analytical skills, including ability to interpret and graphically display environmental performance data\n• Excellent written and verbal communications skills\n• Excellent working knowledge of Microsoft Office\n• Demonstrated professional work characteristics including high initiative, dependability, and ability to manage confidential information\n• Must be well organized and comfortable interfacing with all levels of management\nAmcor Leadership Framework Competencies\n• Drive for Results\n• Influencing Others\n• Customer Focus\n• Learning on the Fly\n• Interpersonal Savvy\n• Organizational Awareness\n• Priority Setting\n• Organizing\n• Functional / Technical Skills\n• Strong Computer Skills\n\nRelationships\n• Amcor Leadership\n• Direct Reports\n• External Vendors\n• Government agencies\n• Global partners/ Nonprofit organizations\n• Industry organizations\nExpected Travel: 10% Travel\n\nThe information contained herein is not intended to be an all-inclusive list of the duties and responsibilities of the job, nor are they intended to be an all-inclusive list of the skills and abilities required to do the job.\n\n#North America",
      "extensions":[
        "Over 1 month ago",
        "Full-time"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title":"Environmental Jobs in Michigan,USA",
      "company_name":"freelancejobopenings.com",
      "location":"Michigan",
      "via":"via Freelance Job Openings",
      "description":"Environmental Jobs in Michigan,USA\n\nSummer Camp Instructor\n\nenvironmental learning center at barr lake state park with a satellite office in fort collins and fieldwork outposts in environmental science, leadership, and or outdoor adventure programs for diverse audiences in formal and non formal outdoor and classroom environmental studies, biological sciences, natural resource management, or related field, with a focus in ornithology.\n\n strong summer, birding, camp, education, colorado, outdoors, teaching\n\nwebsite: barefoot student summer camp\n\nSITE LEAD\n\nenvironmental changes, and sudden work schedule changes.\n• tech savvy: frito lay is an industry leader site: fritolay the site lead is accountable for ensuring the building is operating at top performance to deliver the zone sops strategy and ensures a safe working environment. the role requires cross functional understanding in order to drive operations success.\n\nwe are open 24 hours a day, which means\n\nField Service ... Chromatography Spectrometry Instruments - Grand Rapids, MI\n\nenvironmental testing, and forensic toxicology looking to hire field service engineer to support lcms and gcms platforms. travel to client labs to perform calibrations, diagnose problems with equipment field service chromatography spectrometry instruments grand rapids, mi\n\nleader in liquid chromatography mass spectrometry and gas chromatography mass spectrometry, supporting clinical research, drug discovery, food and environmental testing, and forensic toxicology looking to hire field service engineer to support\n\nUTA Test Engineer\n\nenvironmental demands may be referenced in an attempt to municate the manner in which this position traditionally is performed. about capgemini:\n\na global leader in consulting, technology services and digital transformation, capgemini is at the forefront of innovation to address the entire breadth of clients’ opportunities in the evolving world of cloud, digital and platforms. building on its strong 50 year heritage and deep industry specific expertise, capgemini enables organizations to realize\n\nIndustrial Water/Wastewater Design Engineer\n\nenvironmental, civil, or chemical\n• 4+ years of industrial water wastewater system environmental, civil or chemical\n• water wastewater treatment design experience in variety industrial markets\n• experience with biological and physical chemical treatment design build experience\n\nwhat we offer engineering water wastewater\n\nbusiness line design and consulting services group (dcs)\n\ncountry",
      "extensions":[
        "13 hours ago",
        "Full-time"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want more information, check out [SerpApi documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-jobs-api).